# simplexml_load_file only return partial data of xml

Tags: php, xml

I use simplexml_load_file and expect it can be use on a url, strangely some of the data is missing.

my php

```
$url = "http://www.thestar.com.my/RSS/Lifestyle/Women/";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
```

partial result

```
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [guid] => {936842CF-550D-4CAB-A840-23BB4E766B8E}
                    [link] => http://www.thestar.com.my/Lifestyle/Women/Fashion/2014/07/02/Jamy-Yang-Mingjie-Shared-travelling-values
                    [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [pubDate] => Wed, 02 Jul 2014 00:00:00 +08:00
                    [enclosure] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => http://www.thestar.com.my/~/media/Images/TSOL/Photos-Gallery/features/2014/07/02/JamyYangMingjie020714.ashx?crop=1&w=460&h=345&
                                    [length] => 
                                    [type] => image/jpeg
                                )

                        )

                )
```

`item->title` became SimpleXMLElement Object?

Comment: Yes, and that's **no problem at all**. It's all always a SimpleXMLElement, it's just that you can't use `print_r` with SimpleXMLElement in a useful manner here. See all answers in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot to add an additional parameters to get the `CDATA` Character Data. Try this:

```
$url = "http://www.thestar.com.my/RSS/Lifestyle/Women/";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

When I view the source to that url, all the strings are wrapped with CDATA tags, including the title. According to "wouter at code-b dot nl" at [php:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

"To correctly extract a value from a CDATA just make sure you cast the SimpleXML Element to a string value by using the cast operator"